# Trouble with jquery .hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Having an issue with the jquery .hover function. I am only able to get it to work if I wrap it in a generic `$(function(){`  I have seen it done without needing this generic function, if anyone can see what i am doing wrong I would appreciate it.

This does not Work:

```
$('#slider > img').hover(function () {
    stopLoop();
}, function () {
    startSlider();
});
```

This does work:

```
$(function () {
    $('#slider > img').hover(function () {
        stopLoop();
    }, function () {
        startSlider();
    });
});
```

Comment: That isn't a generic function, it's shorthand for `document.ready`.

Comment: That's not wrapping it in a `generic function`. That's tying it to the document being ready (which is what you want to do). Keep doing it the second way.

Comment: Probably when you retrieve `$('#slider > img')` that element/s is/are not yet on the DOM

Comment: What the others said, document ready and all, as a sidenote you could do ....

Comment: `$('#slider > img').hover(stopLoop, startSlider);`

Comment: Read about the function call you're making: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is You are trying to bind the events to tags while they are not exists in the dom. So Make it in `$(document).ready()` or `$(function()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider > img').hover(function () {
        stopLoop();
    }, function () {
        startSlider();
    });
});
```